# How do you get the database name in a Visual Studio Database project script?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I want to enable change tracking in my database using a Visual Studio database project.

The command is

```
ALTER DATABASE ##database name##
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)
```

but I can't work out the format string to get the database name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `$(DatabaseName)` property. In the .sqlcmdvars file:

> Target database name (set when you deploy). Press F1 for more information.